# SQL: count based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following structure.

```
Flight_ID      |     Source_city    |    DestinatinCity
    1                  NYC                  LONDON
    2                 LONDON                TOKYO
    3                 LONDON                 NYC
```

I want to  found city count i.e cities involved in source and destination,

```
city      | count
LONDON        3
NYC           2
TOKYO         1
```

How can I solve it using basic SQL features(Without PL).

Comment: What's meany by PL?

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian May be Stored Procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `union all` and aggregation.

```
select city,count(*) as cnt
from (
select flight_Id,source_city as city from t
union all 
select flight_Id,destination_city from t
) x
group by city
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with `union all`

```
select source_city as city, count(*) from table_name union all select dest_city,count(*) from table_name group by source_city;
```